# can xpath.evaluate take input from a node(list)?

Tags: java, xpath

I have a giant xml document I need to parse some data from. I have it to the point where I can get the data I need in a NodeList, but then I kinda need to operate on it to get some of the nodes to be together if there are two entries to work on. So I was hoping you can do one evaluate to get the NodeList1 and then run another evaluate on NodeList1 to get NodeList2 that I can then pull out what I need. I could be totally doing this the wrong way.. so here is the xml.

```
    <templateId root="123" />
    <id root="123" />
    <code code="51848-0" codeSystem="123" codeSystemName="LOINC" displayName="Assessments" />
    <title>Visit Diagnoses</title>
    <text>
        <table>
            <colgroup>
                <col width="100%" />
            </colgroup>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Diagnosis</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ID="vdx68" styleCode="normRow">
                    <td>
                        <paragraph>
                            <content ID="vdx68Name">Diagnosis Data 1</content>
                            <content> - Primary</content>
                        </paragraph>
                        <paragraph styleCode="allIndent">secondary diag data related to Primary</paragraph>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr ID="vdx69" styleCode="altRow">
                    <td>
                        <paragraph>
                            <content ID="vdx69Name">Diagnosis Data 2</content>
                        </paragraph>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <footnote ID="subTitle67" styleCode="xSectionSubTitle xHidden">documented in this encounter</footnote>
    </text>
</section>
```

This code gets me to that section and to the "vdx" rows

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='code'][@code='51848-0']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='text']//*[local-name()='tr'][starts-with(@ID,'vdx')]", new InputSource(new StringReader(docString)), XPathConstants.NODESET );

  String diagnosis = null;

  if (null != nodeList) {
     log.debug("node count:" + nodeList.getLength());
     for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        try {
           log.debug("DIAG Node Data:" + nodeList.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent());

           NodeList nodeList2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='paragraph']", nodeList, XPathConstants.NODESET );)
           log.debug("DIAG Node Data2:" + nodeList2.item(i).getFirstChild().getTextContent());

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
     }
  }
```

and gives these traces

```
DIAG Node Data:Diagnosis Data 1 - Primarysecondary diag data related to Primary

DIAG Node Data:Diagnosis Data 2
```

so the data is there.. but I want to get rid of the Primary text and put dash and then the put the secondary after it.

so above you can see I attempted to make a new nodeList2.. but it must throw an exception because it never traces anything out. So I assume I cant even do what I want.. or I just dont have the syntax correct. Not finding much on google for what I'm trying to do...

so anyone have tips on how I should do what I need to do.. or have correct syntax for doing the second evaluate ?

Comment: And why didn't you use the path with `content[starts-with(@ID,"vdx")]` ?

Comment: that would make me miss the secondary diag data node. Which I need to have separate from the first one so I can text format both of them

Comment: “but it must throw an exception” — *Never* write an empty `catch` block.  At the very least, put `e.printStackTrace();` in it.  Then you won’t need to guess.  The exception’s message will probably tell you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: I'll add that trace in. I had it blank because of how some of the xml is formatted that it will always hit that. Really I'm just trying to see if what I'm trying to do is possible ? or am I barking up the wrong tree ? I dont want to keep tinkering with this if this is not something that will ever work.

Comment: so I redid the code and it gives me back data now ```NodeList nodeList2 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("//*[local-name()='paragraph']", nodeList.item(i), XPathConstants.NODESET );``` but for some reason its returning data that is in the whole document, how does it have access to that if I only gave it the nodes that the first one returned ?